# Resolving an array or promises and getting the result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm attempting to map and format data to render it into a table. I have an array of promises that I'm attempting to resolve with Promise.all(). but it seems to not be returning the result of the promise.

my code is as follows:

```
const formatData = (data) => {
  let dataCopy = data;

  if (dataCopy.items && _.has(dataCopy.items[0], 'tenantId')) {
      dataCopy.items = setTenants(dataCopy)
  }

  // format parameters or table render
  // other formatting for the table
  return dataCopy.items.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      created: new Date(item.created).toDateString(),
      updated: new Date(item.updated).toDateString(),
      ...(item.active && { active: item.active.toString() })
  }));
};

const setTenants = (data) => {
  const promises = data.items.map(item => {
      return getTenant(item)
  })
  return Promise.all(promises).then(res => { return res })
}

const getTenant = (row) => {
  return tenantService.getTenantById(row.tenantId).then(res => {
      // set name as the tenant param for the table
      row.tenant = res.name
      return row
  });
}
```

my data copy variable only returns as :

```
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(10)
```

where the result is the correct result of the 'setTenants' function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an array of promises that I'm attempting to resolve with `Promise.all()`.

`Promise.all` doesn't resolve promises (or I think you mean settle¹ in this case). It allows you to *observe* the result of promises being settled. It doesn't *make* them settle.

Your `setTenants` function returns a promise. To use its fulfillment value, you have to use `.then` or `await` (in an `async` function). Remember that as of when `setTenants` returns its promise, the operations that have been started *may not have completed yet*.

So

```
setTenants(/*...*/)
.then(results => {
    // use results...
})
.catch(error => {
    // handle/report error
});
```

Or, in an `async` function:

```
const results = await setTenants(/*...*/);
```

(Perhaps with a `try`/`catch` to handle rejection, although often you'll want to just let that propagate to the caller and handle it there.)

---

Side note: The `then` callback in this code is pointless:

```
return Promise.all(promises).then(res => { return res })
```

It should just be:

```
return Promise.all(promises);
```

---

¹ Some promise terminology:

- *fulfill* - To change a promise state from *pending* to *fulfilled* with a specific *fulfillment value*
- *reject* - To change a promise state from *pending* to *rejected* with a specific *rejection reason*
- *resolve* - To determine the eventual outcome of a promise, either directly (by fulfilling or rejecting it) or indirectly (by making its outcome depend on the outcome of another promise)

It's important to realize that a resolved promise will still be pending if it's *resolved to* another promise and that other promise is pending.

Here's an example:

```js
const p1 = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 800, 42);
});

// This could also be written: `const p2 = Promise.resolve(p1);`
const p2 = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(p1);
});

// At this point, both `p1` and `p2` are *pending*; `p2` is *resolved to*
// `p1`, but neither `p1` nor `p2` is *settled* yet

p2
.then(value => {
    // At this point, `p2` is *fulfilled* (one of the two kinds of *settled*)
    console.log(value);
})
.catch(error => {
    // At this point, `p2` is *rejected* (one of the two kinds of *settled*)
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 8 of my new book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.